# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.copy(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/io/OutputStream;)

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to read the xmlsx file using poi API, when i execute the code in my local system its executes fine but in server it throws exception

> NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.util.IOUtils.copy(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/io/OutputStream;)

i am currently using the latest POI api.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there also is an earlier version of POI on the classpath in which that method did not exist yet. See [this question in the POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006).

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with transitive dependencies or a conflict with existing libraries in the servlet container your deploying in.